# Is it possible to hide the Toolbar and disable the scroll when swiping to specific page?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, toolbar

I would like to be able to hide the Toolbar on swipe to a specific tab and then lock it. Expanding it and then locking would also work for me although i prefer the first.

I have tried doing stuff like in the code below, but it gives rise to some snappy behavior because the page is scrolled of the screen originally. As soon as i set the scroll flags to 0, the whole page snaps back up and then locks the screen with the toolbar expanded which makes sense because with scroll flags set to zero, the page should not be able to scroll off the screen at all so it just snaps back up.

The page I am tending to is a chat page and in order to have a static text input bar at the bottom I really need to disable the scrolling for that page while making it possible for the others.

Can you guys think of some way to accomplish this?

Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_group);
    appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbar);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // add all the needed fragments for the tabs inside a Vector
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    viewPager.clearOnPageChangeListeners();
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayoutOnPageChangeListenerGroups(tabLayout, this, fab, appBarLayout));

    viewPager.setCurrentItem(CURRENT_TAB);
}

public void disableToolbarScrolling()
{
    logger.d("disabling scrolling toolbar");
    AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
    params.setScrollFlags(0);  // clear all scroll flags
    toolbar.setLayoutParams(params);
}

public void enableToolbarScrolling()
{
    logger.d("enabling scrolling toolbar");
    AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
    params.setScrollFlags(AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL | AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_ENTER_ALWAYS);  // clear all scroll flags
    toolbar.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

And then using a PageChangeListener to handle the event:

```
public TabLayoutOnPageChangeListenerGroups(TabLayout tabLayout, Activity activity, FloatingActionsMenu fab, AppBarLayout appBarLayout)
{
    ...
    this.appBarLayout = appBarLayout;
    ...
}

private void enableScrolling()
{
    ((GroupActivity) mActivity).enableToolbarScrolling();
    toolbarState = toolbarState_enabled;
}

private void disableScrolling()
{
    ((GroupActivity) mActivity).disableToolbarScrolling();
    toolbarState = toolbarState_disabled;
}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position)
{
    if(position == 0)
    {
        logger.d("pos 0");
        disableScrolling();
        appBarLayout.setExpanded(false);
    }
    else
    {
        logger.d("pos != 0");
        enableScrolling();
    }
}
```

EDIT 1:

I have tried setting toolbar visibility to both GONE or INVISIBLE. But they only make the toolbar white, giving a white bar at the top of the screen. Still allowing for the scrolling behaviour.

Comment: Have you tried it . toolbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

Comment: @KhizarHayat hmmm,, ill try it out

Comment: @KhizarHayat   no,, it just makes the toolbar invisible while still allowing the scroll.. Basically giving me a white bar at the top of the screen.

Comment: didn't get your quistian ..  you want to allow swiping only when toolbar is visible ?

Comment: @saleed, I have one page in which i want to disable the toolbar scrolling behaviour. That page is a chat page that has a textinput at the bottom. When toolbar scrolling is enabled, the textinput bar scrolls up and down when user scrolls the chat list. I want the textinput to be fixxed at the bottom while allowing toolbar scroll on the other pages.

Answer (score 0):

add this line to your code in `onCreate`
`setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` and then add
`toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Comment: try it with supportAction

Comment: aah sorry,, already had that in my code. The code I have posted is not everything i have,, i tried making a Minimal Working Example.

Answer (score 0):

For hiding the toolbar you can just try :

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Comment: hmmmm,, gonna try it out.

Comment: hiding it still allows for the page to be scrolled on and off screen.